# How to Output Raw Binary as Raw Hex in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, binary

Okay, I see thousands of different answers for messing with binary yet none of them seem to do what I want. I have a raw binary file. Unreadable. Not ASCII. Not hex. If you open in text pad it is all gibberish characters like "      ÿûÿû      ÿûÿû      ÿ". I want to read the raw binary values and write those values in hex. The first 8 bits might be a value of 0xAA also known as b10101010 or decimal 170 and ascii is a superscript letter a. I want that raw AA to be printed and I want to do this with 32 bytes at a time. I don't want to print "      ÿûÿû      ÿûÿû      ÿ". I want to print **"0003200320032000050005fffbfffb0000000000000fffbfffb"**. I also do not want to end up with b'\x00\x03 \x03 \x03 \x00\x05\x00\x05\xff\xfb\xff\xfb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfb\xff\xfb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff'or even b'\xfb00000000FFFBFFFB000000000000FFF' or whatever other weird things get returned when parsing binary files. And I absolutely need all leading zeros. How do I get what I want? Thanks!!

Comment: Wow, I really thought this was an easy question to be answered in a few minutes! Haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out something that works half-decent. Seems wrong to cast the byte-object thingy as a string, but maybe that's the best way?

```
import binascii

f = open(<FILENAME/PATH>, "rb")

# hexlify gives bytes object but looks like b'0xabcdef1234' when converted to a string:
hexString = str(binascii.hexlify(f.read(0x20))) 

# grabs just the abcd1234 part:
hexString = hexString.split("'")[1].upper().replace('0X','')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read from standard input and write the hex representation to standard output.  You can adjust it to open and read from a file (remember to open with mode `'rb'`) or take a `file` argument or whatever meets your needs.

```
def hexdump():
  while True:
    data = sys.stdin.read(32)
    if not data:
      return
    for byte in data:
      sys.stdout.write('%02x' % (ord(byte)))
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: thanks, this works extremely well. in my case i had to cast by byte to char first "ord(chr(byte))", but i am receiving data from nordic board via BLE